# Phonegap ondeviceready event in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

Hello i am using angularjs to create an phonegap app. Here is my controller:

```
module.controller('MainController', function($scope, $window, $rootScope){
$scope.funda="new Funda";
    $scope.deviceReady = false;
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    console.log('mainCtrl is loaded');

    function onOnline(){
                alert('device is in online mode'); //cannot reach here
                $rootScope.online = true;
                $scope.online = $rootScope.online;
    }
    function onOffline(){
                alert('device is not ready');
                $rootScope.online = false;
                $scope.online = $rootScope.online;
            }

    function onDeviceReady() {
       $scope.$apply(function() {
            alert('device is ready'); //Its Reaching here fine
            document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
            document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
            $scope.deviceReady = true;
        });
    }
});
```

It seems like are `onDeviceReady` this function is triggering well but after that i can reach to `onOnline` function.

Is there is any another method for invoking the deviceready function in angularjs.

Thank you!

Comment: You mean online/offline functions are not being triggered? You will need to add org.apache.cordova.network-information plugin to do that, so be sure if you already have added it.

Comment: Yes i added the plugin already, but still its not triggering.

Comment: And even i checked through console.log but there is no error so far just 2 things

"deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
cordova.js:1167 Channel not fired: onCordovaConnectionReady"

Answer (score 1):

the answer i find by myself. And it was very easy. Angular has its own way to figure this out. Here is what you have to do only.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
     alert(navigator.network.connection.type);
}
```

and this will tell you the connection type.